# Workaround for unsupported SETSTAT request on SFTP server with sshj

Tags: java, sftp, sshj, aws-sftp

I'm trying to SFTP to a server using identity string: SSH-2.0-AWS_SFTP_1.0 with the following Java code using sshj.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hierynomus</groupId>
    <artifactId>sshj</artifactId>
    <version>0.29.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
private SSHClient setupSshj(String remoteHost, String username, String password) throws IOException {
    SSHClient client = new SSHClient();
    client.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
    client.connect(remoteHost);
    client.authPassword(username, password);
    return client;
}

public void sftpfiles() throws IOException {
    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(GetConfigValue("dds", "sendFiles"))) {
        SSHClient sshClient = setupSshj(GetConfigValue("dds", "RemoteAddress"), GetConfigValue("dds", "RemoteLogin"), GetConfigValue("dds", "RemotePassword"));
        SFTPClient sftpClient = sshClient.newSFTPClient();
        sftpClient.put("/home/vm/test.txt", GetConfigValue("dds", "RemoteDirectory"));
        sftpClient.close();
        sshClients.disconnect();
    }
}
```

and get the error

> Error SETSTAT unsupported

I understand that the AWS service doesn’t allow setting timestamps when uploading however I don't know what adjustments are required in order to configure the SFTP client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that sshj [`SSHClient`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.hierynomus/sshj/latest/net/schmizz/sshj/SSHClient.html) API does not allow preventing the use of the SETSTAT request. You will have to use more low level API, like [`SFTPFileTransfer`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.hierynomus/sshj/latest/net/schmizz/sshj/sftp/SFTPFileTransfer.html):

```
SFTPEngine engine = new SFTPEngine(sshClient).init();
SFTPFileTransfer xfer = new SFTPFileTransfer(engine);
xfer.setPreserveAttributes(false);
xfer.upload("/home/vm/test.txt", GetConfigValue("dds", "RemoteDirectory"));
```

Answer (score 9):

SSHJ does support skipping SETSTAT method.

```
sftpClient.getFileTransfer().setPreserveAttributes(false)
```

Answer (score -1):

> By default the preserveAttributes of SFTPFileTransfer is true

```
 [private volatile boolean preserveAttributes = true;]
```

Hence, setting it to false for AWS services would stop preserving data during uploads.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.